# http.get request not executing

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs, get

I have been trying to figure out this problem for the last few hours and to the life of me I can't figure out what is wrong.

I have used both the debugging tools with netbeans and with chrome dev-tools and both seem to just skip it without trying to even execute it as I'm getting neither a error or success in fact I don't even get a xHR request sent off to collect the file.

**Factory:**

```
.factory('Stories', function($http) {
    var factory = {};
    var stories = [];
    factory.status;


    $http.get('../json/stories.json')
    .success(function(data,status){
        stories = data;
        factory.status = status;
    })
    .error(function(data,status){
        stories = data || "request faild";
        factory.status = status;
    });

    factory.getStory = function() {

        return stories;
    };
})
```

This is only a section of the app but is contained so I don't think you will need the rest. if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great Thanks in advance.

Comment: both `success` and `error` not executing?

Comment: yeh its very strange the http function is being injected find just nothing is happening

Comment: I assume your actual code isn't minimized, but in case it is, perhaps the format .factory('Stories', ['$http', function($http) { ...] would help

Comment: nope didn't seem to help thanks anyways

Comment: Are you actually injecting your `Stories` service anywhere? Services in Angular are instantiated lazily, that is, only when they are actually requested.

Comment: does removing the previous line "factory.status" help? Seems redundant.

Comment: And in Chrome dev tools, does $http exists? Does it have a get() function. Try stepping into it (perhaps comment out the success & error functions so it's just a straight function call to make sure it works).

Comment: ill give your suggestions a try and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Fix it

For reference incase someone else comes accross a similar problems.

Check first:

1. check what is displaying the factory that the variables matchup
2. Make sure $http is being injected to param
3. set aliases for each of your params that are being injected

this was my final solution:

```
.factory('Stories', ['$http', function($http) {

    var factory = {};
    var stories = null;

    stories = $http.get('./json/stories.json')
    .success(function(data){
        stories = data;

    });    
    factory.getStory = function() {      
        return stories;
    };  
    return factory;
}]);
```